# I am unable to connect to wifi. Settings > Wi-Fi shows "No adapter found" in 18.04 UBUNTU. Using an hp pavilion g6 2313ax

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, ralink

As most of the questions start with "I am new to Ubuntu". I am not so new to Ubuntu, familiar since 16.04 now recently upgraded to 18.04 and my WiFi is not working properly ever since,I freshly installed 18.04 but still facing the issue so figured as always read some blogs and see some videos to fix that but no use. I a using hp pavilion g6 2314ax. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[output of 'lshw -C network'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtlHL.png)

lspci output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

sudo modprobe rt2800pci && dmesg | grep rt2 output :

```
[   31.824511] rt2800pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   31.824729] rt2800pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT ?: not connected
[   31.824823] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_probe_rt: Error - Invalid RT chipset 0xffff, rev ffff detected
[   31.824829] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_probe_dev: Error - Failed to allocate device
[ 6981.825491] Modules linked in: rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core edac_mce_amd snd_hwdep snd_pcm kvm_amd kvm uvcvideo irqbypass videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 wl(POE) videobuf2_core videodev crct10dif_pclmul media crc32_pclmul rt2800pci ghash_clmulni_intel rt2800mmio rt2800lib pcbc snd_seq_midi aesni_intel rt2x00pci rt2x00mmio rt2x00lib snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 aes_x86_64 cfg80211 snd_rawmidi eeprom_93cx6 crypto_simd rtsx_pci_ms memstick k10temp glue_helper cryptd input_leds joydev snd_seq wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_seq_device hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_timer snd hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev shpchp hp_wireless soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables
[14937.107712] usb usb5-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci && dmesg | grep rt2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the error:

```
rt2800_probe_rt: Error - Invalid RT chipset
```

A search for the error returns this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257359

> Ok so it didn't work on win7 either so I plugged it out and cleaned
>   everything with vacuum cleaned, and it just worked!

And this: https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2015-11/msg03170.html

> The problem appears likely either a BIOS or a hardware problem, so I
>   would
>       check BIOS setup (reset, or complete clear by removing CMOS battery) and
>       proofing the WiFi adapter connection.

In this context, I believe that “...proofing the WiFi adapter connection” means to make sure that the contacts are clean and the card is securely seated in the PCI slot. Basically, that means exactly the same as the above post.

In short, I believe it is a hardware issue and not a driver or operating system issue.